# Python Flask blueprint without static folder for css and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, css, flask, apache2

I have searched similar answer to this and found to no avail.

Using CGI Handler Apache server with an index.cgi

I have to adhere the strict policy on the directory list; they're adamantly refused to have a static folder in the directory for Flask.

I kinda wish Flask add static_js and static_css that would make our life easier.

How do I override the static folder?

It works with a single path for either css or javascript:

```
# in app.py
app.register_blueprint(index_bp)
app.add_url_rule('/css/<path:filename>', endpoint='css', view_func=app.send_static_file)

app.add_url_rule('/js/<path:filename>', endpoint='js', view_func=app.send_static_file)
```

```
# css_dir = /parent_folder/css and read from json load
from config import css_dir

index = Blueprint('index', __name__, template_folder=html_dir, static_folder=css_dir)

# in html file
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('css', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">

# note: javascript won't load at all
```

or

```
# js_dir = /parent_folder/js and read from json load
from config import js_dir

index = Blueprint('index', __name__, template_folder=html_dir, static_folder=css_dir)

# in the html file
<script type ="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('js', filename='lib/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

# note: css won't load at all
```

but does not work:

```
# multi_dir = /parent_folder and read from json load
from config import multi_dir

index = Blueprint('index', __name__, template_folder=html_dir, static_folder=multi_dir)

# in html file
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('css', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">

<script type ="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('js', filename='lib/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

# note: both won't load at all
```

I want to include javascript and css folders without a static folder

1. parent_folder

   - cgi-bin

     - python/perl stuff
   - templates

     - html stuff
   - css

     - css stuff
   - js

     - lib

       - javascript stuff

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it can be achieved by create a two python files and register them in the app.py blueprint.

Since Stack Overflow won't let me post code in here due to error which is in correct format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).